# Recibir datos por ajax y mostrar en distintos Select

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Explico lo que tengo primero.
Tengo un Select cargado con varios datos (motores)

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
<select name="mmotor" id="mmotor" class="form-control" onchange="selmmotor()" required></select></div>
```

Al seleccionar un dato del select "mmotor" debo cargar 2 selects más, con info de la bd
Actualmente tengo funcionando uno de estos select (cajas totales)
El primer select:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
<select name="cajaM" id="cajaM" class="form-control" onchange="selcajam()" required="required" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="">Seleccione</option>
</select></div>
```

Y se carga con los todos los valores de acuerdo al select "mmotor" con la función "selmmotor()"

```
function selmmotor() {
var id = $("#mmotor :selected").val();
var dataString = 'motorid='+ id;

if (id != "Seleccione"){
    $.ajax({
    url: url_dominio+"crud/getCajaM.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function(){},
    success: function(response){
        $('#cajaM').html(response);
    },
    error: function(xhr){
        alert("Error: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
    }
    });
}else {
clrvalores();
}}
```

El PHP

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['motorid'])){
    require_once('../class/connects.php');
    $query = "SELECT id,modelo FROM bd_cajam ORDER BY id ASC";
    if($result = $db->query($query)){
        $html="<option value=''>Seleccione</option>";
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $html.="<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['modelo']."</option>";
        }
    }
    $result->free();
    $db->close;
    echo $html;
}?>
```

Luego necesito cargar otro select con algunos valores del select "cajaM", que son los valores de cajas recomendadas, utilizando la misma función

```
<select name="cajaRec" id="cajaRec" class="form-control" onchange="selcajam()" required="required" disabled="disabled">
        <option value="">Seleccione</option>
</select>
```

El php lo puedo colocar en el mismo archivo y sería así, solo cambia el query

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['motorid'])){
    require_once('../class/connects.php');
    $query = "SELECT C.id AS id, C.modelo AS modelo, M.id_engine 
                FROM bd_cajam AS C INNER JOIN bd_cajaxmotor AS R ON C.id = R.id_cajam INNER JOIN bd_engine AS M ON R.id_engine = M.id_engine 
                WHERE M.id_engine = $id_motor";
    if($result = $db->query($query)){
        $html="<option value=''>Seleccione</option>";
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $html.="<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['modelo']."</option>";
        }
    }
    $result->free();
    $db->close;
    echo $html;
}?>
```

Ahora lo que quisiera es utilizar la misma función selmmotor() para hacer todo, mi ppregunta es como podría enviar y recibir ambos resultados con el ajax, no tengo mucha experiencia con el tema, ni con json
Porque podría copiar la función de nuevo

```
function selmmotor() {
    var id = $("#mmotor :selected").val();
    var dataString = 'motorid='+ id;

    if (id != "Seleccione"){
        $.ajax({
        url: url_dominio+"crud/getCajaM.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function(){},
        success: function(response){
            $('#cajaRec').html(response);
        },
        error: function(xhr){
            alert("Error: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }
        });
    }else {
    clrvalores();
    }}
```

Es decir, a la final puedo copiar y pegar la funcion y tener 2 archivos php, o utilizando una variable action para distinguir en el php las diferentes query's pero no es lo que quiero
Quisiera recibir los dos resultados con un mismo ajax y mostrarlos en los dos Select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como lo dices no tienes experiencia con `json`, debes estudiar `json` no hay de otra:

***Documentacion*** 
Que es: [Link-1](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp) 
Como se integra con ajax: [Jquery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) o [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Como lo solucionas, bueno, en el backend en php debes crear un string json para tu respuesta:

***Documentacion*** 
Que es: [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php) 
Como se integra con ajax: [Link-2](https://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_json_php.asp)

***Ejemplo:***

```php
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
$obj = json_decode($_GET["x"], false);

$conn = new mysqli("myServer", "myUser", "myPassword", "Northwind");
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name FROM customers LIMIT ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $obj->limit);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$outp = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($outp);
```

como podrás observar, después de obtener datos de una base de dato y tratar la información el resultado es pasado por `json_encode` de tal manera puedes hacerlo si todo lo que necesitas lo manejas en un array como este:

```php
$resultado1 = [];//resultado de la base de datos
$resultado2 = [];//resultado de la base de datos
$arr = [];
$arr['select1'] = $resultado1;
$arr['select2'] = $resultado2;

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Con esta teoría y conceptos deberías poder adaptarlo y solucionar tu problema.